# Decompile APK built with Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

Good day all.
I need get C# source code from an apk, I tried a few days ways, but they give me java code.

I built a little game in c# xamarin. I stopped working on it for a while, and now I want continue building it, but I've lost the source code. I have an apk file but cannot get the source code. If there is any way get the source code? Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get the source code from an APK file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3593420/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-source-code-from-an-apk-file)

Comment: and also https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30115/is-there-a-xamarin-android-decompiler

Comment: I want get C# sorse, that metod giving me java, so it is not dublicate.

Comment: Fixed use https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/ decombiler. thanks all.

Answer (score 20):

first, extract apk using 7zip or winrar. you can also use APKTool

then go to the assemblies folder and open {appname}.dll with [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy/releases) or [dotPeek](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/). if you're not using Microsoft Windows, there's a cross-platform tool called [AvaloniaILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvaloniaILSpy/releases).

if you don't see the dll file (only .so files) you need to unpack it with [this](https://github.com/AigioL/unpack.libmonodroid_bundle_app.so/releases/tag/v1.0.0.0) tool.

I opened with dnSpy

[image]

Comment: What if there are only `.so` files?

Comment: in unity they are compiled by il2cpp and you have to load the so files in a disassembler like IDA or Ghidra.

Comment: Since 2020, Xamarin DLLs might be compressed with LZ4 (it was introduced in this PR: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/pull/4686), so decompilers like dotPeek are not able to read them (yet). You have to decompress them manually first. This is described here: https://www.x41-dsec.de/security/news/working/research/2020/09/22/xamarin-dll-decompression/

Answer (score 1):

First use apktools to unpack apk

then use "https://github.com/tjg1/mono_unbundle" to unpack "libmonodroid_bundle_app.so"

then you will get <your_app_name>.dll

open it by dnSpy

Comment: The original repository is no longer available. The new address is "https://github.com/talshimoni/mono_unbundle/"

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the above solutions are deprecated after compression APK with the LZ4 algorithm.

The best solution I could find is in [this GitHub project](https://github.com/jakev/pyxamstore).
After applying the steps on the GitHub link, I could obtain the DLLs and finally decompile them with `dotPeek` or another app.