# Is there a way to live debug an then patch an APK which has been built with Xamarin but I do not have the source?

Tags: debugging, xamarin, apk, reverse-engineering, reflexil

Is there a way to live debug an APK which has been built with Xamarin but I do not have the source?  I'm looking to set breakpoints while debugging the de-compiled code (which I have done successfully).  Most of the functionality is in DLL files now though, not JAR files like a few years ago when I did this last.

I tried modifying the uncompressed DLLs with Reflexil via .NET Reflector, then re-compressing and re-signing, but the format of the DLL seems to be incorrect when saving from Reflexil/.NET Reflector and the modified APK does not load on the device.

Comment: Maybe the link below would be helpdul. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097544/decompile-apk-built-with-xamarin

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have done the decompiling portion already as I described in my original question.  I'm looking to live debug and patch the APK.

Comment: You could debug the decompiling code not the APK.

Comment: thanks @WendyZang-MSFT - do you have any advice on how to actually run the decompiled code or attach the debugger to the running process on a mobile device or Emulator?

Comment: You could check the tool you used to decompile could debug or not.