# Difficulty with reverse engineering xamarin apk

Tags: xamarin

I was making an app and I lost the source code because I didn't back it up, but I have this app in debug mode installed on my smatphone. I was able to extract the APK. I'd like to reverse engineer it and get some of my time back, but I can't. When unpacking it I have the result as the image shows.

[image: my result]

Does not have .dll. I tried the suggestions in this question but to no avail.

[Question 44097544](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44097544/decompile-apk-built-with-xamarin)

Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to get the bundle DLL. But, in new version, Xamarin converts the code into the `assemblies.blob`.

Try this: https://www.thecobraden.com/posts/unpacking_xamarin_assembly_stores/